# I want to replace $ with 1- in a pandas series ,how can i do that

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.Series(['12', '-$10', '$10,000'])
df.replace(to_replace='$', value=None ,method='bfill')
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df = pd.Series(['12', '-$10', '$10,000'])
df = df.to_frame()
df[0] = df[0].str.replace('$', '1')
print(df)
```